# Pickle python closure

Tags: python, closures, pickle

This is my custom objective function for my lightGBM model. However, I cannot pickle my model due to the closure. Is there a work around? My objective function can be seen below:

```
def custom_asymmetric_train_wrapper(delta,tau):
   def custom_asymmetric_train(y_true, y_pred):
       residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
       grad = np.where(residual>0, -2*delta*residual, -2*residual)
       hess = np.where(residual>0, 2*tau, 2.0)
      return grad, hess
   return custom_asymmetric_train
```

I have tried joblib as well as adding the parameters delta and tau to the custom_asymmetric_train function

Answer (score 2):

The closure holds the `delta` and `tau` values used on each call. But classes are picklable and do the same thing with a bit more typing.

```
class CustomAsymmetricTrain:

    def __init__(self, delta, tau):
        self.delta = delta
        self.tau = tau
        
    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred):
       residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
       grad = np.where(residual>0, -2*self.delta*residual, -2*residual)
       hess = np.where(residual>0, 2*self.tau, 2.0)
      return grad, hess
```

Instantiate the class with `delta` and `tau` values and then call the resulting object as needed. Using highly contrived data:

```
custom_asymetric_train_1 = CustomAsymmetricTrain(1, 2)
result1 = custom_asymetric_train_1(3, 4)
result2 = custom_asymetric_train(4, 5)
```

Comment: How do I set the objective to my model?

    `train_objective = CustomAsymmetricTrain(delta,tau)`
    `lgb_model.set_params(**{'objective': train_objective}, metrics=['custom_asymmetric_valid'])`

I now do the following however, I get the error: TypeError: Unknown type of parameter:objective, got:CustomAsymmetricTrain

Comment: That's unexpected. I don't know why an api would take a closure but not other callables. I don't know anything about lightGBM specifically so hard to say. It seems from the [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.set_params) that objective can be any callable. You could look at the source around the line that failed to see how it tests for callable.